# JSON module for python 2.4?

Tags: python, json, python-2.4

I'm accustomed to doing `import json` in Python 2.6, however I now need to write some code for Python 2.4.  Is there a JSON library with a similar interface that is available for Python 2.4?

Comment: Did you try `simplejson`?  How did it work?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `json` module in Python 2.6 is mostly the same as the `simplejson` third-party module, which is available for Python 2.4 as well. You can just do:

```
try:
    import json
except ImportError:
    import simplejson as json
```

Comment: Python 2.4 is no longer supported by the latest versions of simplejson.

Comment: You can get simplejson for 2.4 from here: https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.4/s/simplejson/

Answer (score 26):

Now, a few years later, simplejson does only support python 2.5+. No more simplejson for systems stuck on 2.4. Even though it is not supported, you may find older packages on pypi. 2.0.9 or 2.1.0 should work.

```
pip install simplejson==2.1.0
```

(I could not comment on the chosen answer, but this just bit me hard, so it may be useful to others as well)

Comment: Good hint, you're not the only one "stuck" on 2.4!

Comment: and for those who don't know the syntax: pip install simplejson==2.1.0

Answer (score 2):

I needed to get this up on an old box with Python 2.4.3.
Used simplejson-1.7-py2.4.egg from here:

https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.4/s/simplejson/